# cannot call client from button in sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm working in sockets with digital signature RSA with MD5 algorithms.I want to add a button to open server form and other for server I used threads it wworks with server but failed with client form. it open but no action or some thing and i cannot close it from the cross above
code for server

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Server s=new Server();
    new Thread(s).start();
    try{
    s.getKeys();
   s.run();
    }catch(Exception e){}

    }
```

for client

```
Client c=new Client();

new Thread(c).start();
try{

c.setVisible(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
c.getKeys();
c.run();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

in main client.java

```
      @Override
  public void run()  {   
    // connect to server, get streams, process connection   
    try {  
        client = new Socket(chatServer, 12345);
        connectToServer(); 
        getStreams();   
        processConnection();   
        closeConnection();
      }   

     // server closed connection   
    catch (Exception e) {   
        System.err.println("Client terminated connection");   
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are both starting threads from your `Runnables` and running them. Remove both `run()` calls. They don't make sense.

Comment: I deleted it but also client frame cannot read the message from text file to send it to server

Comment: String rawMessage=this.readFromFile("F:\\test-1.txt"); 
            this.displayMessage("Original information："+rawMessage); 
            String messageDigest=MD5Encrypt.MD5Encode(rawMessage); 
            this.displayMessage("Info summery："+messageDigest);    
            byte[] DS =RSAUtil.encrypt(PRK, messageDigest.getBytes()); 
            this.displayMessage("digital signature："+new String(DS));

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it is totally illegible. Also you haven't told us what it is *for*, or what exactly 'cannot read the message' means. Put all this into your question.

Comment: NB It isn't clear why you would encrypt a message digest, but `new String(byte[])` just displays a string like `Object.toString()` does: not the content of the byte array at all. If you want to display it you will need to hex-encode it.